# Usando k-means particionado

Tags: k-means

Boa tarde. Tenho um data-set com 5.700 observações, uma das variáveis é "nota", onde a mesma varia de 0 a 10 para cada observação. Gostaria de saber se é possível rodar o k-means, usando o RStudio, da seguinte maneira: criar 09 clusters de modo que a nota 2,68 seja o centro, dividindo 04 clusters acima dessa nota e 05 clusters abaixo dessa nota.

Na realidade o que fiz foi dividir a base em duas partes, base "a" e base "b":
a<-base_mod_final_kn%>% filter(score_comp >= 0 & score_comp < 2.63)
b<-base_mod_final_kn%>% filter(score_comp >= 2.63 & score_comp <= 10)

Logo após, rodei o k-means nas duas partes:
k_a <- kmeans(a$score_comp, 5, iter.max=10, nstart=5)
k_b <- kmeans(b$score_comp, 4, iter.max=10, nstart=5)

Depois juntei as bases novamente. Isso resolveu meu problema, mas gostaria de saber se não teria um método alternativo que usemos só o k-means sem ter quer particionar a base.

Comment: Poderia postar algumas linhas do dataset (só para ter um ideia de como está estruturado os dados) ? Poderia adicionar uma tag relacionando qual programa está utilizando para fazer as operações?